# Activity doesn't start

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I created a new activity which is supposed to read elements in a text file then display them as a `ListView`, but when I try to start the activity by clicking on its icon in the emulator I get this error message :

> Unfortunately, app has stopped working

I don't understand why because the project seems to have been compiled correctly ?

PS : The activity I try to open is `SortedLocationsListActivity`.

**Logcat error message :**

```
02-04 13:51:32.340    2900-2900/fr.isima.android.tp1.tp1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: fr.isima.android.tp1.tp1, PID: 2900
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fr.isima.android.tp1.tp1/fr.isima.android.tp1.tp2.SortedLocationsListActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "1400390852000A"
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "1400390852000A"
            at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:124)
            at java.lang.Long.parse(Long.java:366)
            at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:353)
            at fr.isima.android.tp1.tp2.SortedLocationsListActivity.onCreate(SortedLocationsListActivity.java:37)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Here is a part of my SortedLocationsListActivity (I modified the onCreate method) :

```
public class SortedLocationsListActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_sorted_locations_list);


        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.locations);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        List<String> maListe = new ArrayList<String>();
        String myligne;
        LocationAdapter adapter = new LocationAdapter(this, R.layout.row_location);

        try {
            while((myligne = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String a[] = myligne.split(";");
                Long _date=Long.parseLong(a[2], 36);
                System.out.println(a[0]+" "+a[1]+" "+a[2]);
                adapter.addLocation(a[0],a[1],_date);
            }
            setListAdapter(adapter);

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }


    }
```

Ok, so the code that causes the problem is :

```
Long _date=Long.parseLong(a[2], 36);
```

Basically want I'm trying to do is to convert a `String` which can be "1400390852000A" for example to the Long type, how can I do it correctly ?

Ok, I corrected the error and I have managed to start the activity but it only displays a blank screen instead of the list I want, Here is the adapter that i coded :

```js
public class LocationAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private List<Location> Locations;
        int monLayout;
        LayoutInflater inflater;


        public LocationAdapter(Context context, int layout){
            monLayout=layout;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            Locations = new ArrayList<Location>();
        }



        private class Location{
            public String name;
            public String address;
            public Long date;

            public Location(String _name,String _address , Long _date){
                name=_name;
                address=_address;
                date=_date;

            }
        }


        private class ViewHolder{

            TextView name_view;
            TextView address_view;
            TextView date_view;

            public ViewHolder(View rowLayout){

                name_view = (TextView)rowLayout.findViewById(R.id.name);
                date_view = (TextView)rowLayout.findViewById(R.id.date);
                address_view = (TextView)rowLayout.findViewById(R.id.address);
            }
        }

        public void addLocation(String _name,String _address,Long _date){
            //Création d'une nouvelle location avec les données en paramètres
            Location new_loc = new Location(_name, _address,_date);

            //Ajout de la location à la liste des locations
            Locations.add(new_loc);

        }
    /*Méthodes de la classe mère*/

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = convertView;

            if (view == null)
                view = inflater.inflate(monLayout, parent, false);

            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
            if (holder == null)
            {
                holder = new ViewHolder(view);
                view.setTag(holder);
            }

            Location location = (Location)getItem(position);

            holder.name_view.setText(location.name);
            holder.address_view.setText(location.address);
            holder.date_view.setText("Test");

            return view;
        }
}
```

Can someone tell me where the problem may come from ?

Comment: it calls unhandlled exceptions. See logs in DDMS windows Logcat view and post them here. 

Did you declare your activity in manifest?

Comment: How can you even expect anyone to help you without your application code and `Stack Trace` or better known as `Logcat`

Comment: Post some code or a Stack Trace, we can't help you much if we don't know what's going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is this >>    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "1400390852000A"

You are trying to convert String type to Long by `Long.parseLong` in your activity. Correct this and it will work.

String value >> 1400390852000A, can not be converted to Long.

check your `SortedLocationsListActivity` line number 37. Bug is there, go kill it :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to line 37 of SortedLocationsListActivity class and check for a Long parsing method. Make sure that the parameter in this is always a number.

```
Long _date=Long.parseLong(a[2], 36);
```

Make sure that String myligne, after the ;, has only numbers.

> Basically want I'm trying to do is to convert a String wich can be "1400390852000A" for example to the Long type, how can I do it correctly ?

It depends on the format of your Strings. If it's always the case that the letter is at the end then you can get the number by adding this in your code, just before the parsing:

```
String a[] = myligne.split(";");
String myFinalString =  a[2].substring(0, a[2].length()-1);
Long _date=Long.parseLong(myFinalString, 36);
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at SortedLocationsListActivity line 37.

it's look's like an  NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "1400390852000A".

check the parameters here:

```
Long _date=Long.parseLong(a[2], 36);
```